# extract n levels links from URL using wget

Tags: bash, shell, wget

> I am trying to extract URLS from a webpage up to user defined n levels
>   using wget. I tried this

```
 wget -r -l$2 --reject=gif -O out.html www.google.com | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'` "
```

> It is displaying only the first level. it is not parsing any levels
>   how could i rectify it

Comment: What do you mean by "levels"?

Comment: @shoover: -l2, -l3.. etc 
Number is taken as argument

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems in the command line

```
wget -r -l$2 --reject=gif -O out.html www.google.com | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'` "
```

1. There are superfluous ` and " at the end of the command. They are probably copy paste error.
2. The running `sed 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'` is little bit naive because most the page can have a lot of references on the same line and some tags may be split over several lines.
3. The regexp has not ending `"` so reference plus rest of line is printed
4. The output is written to file `out.html` and nothing is forwarded to the stdout. It can be changed by the option `-O -`. Unfortunately this option does not work well with `-r` and `-lx`. So solution is to store the result and execute two commands.
5. www.google.com may return `302 Found` with location pointing to localized google and wget does not recurse to this localized page.

So the working command could be (not tested - written just for your inspiration):

```
$ wget  -nv -r -l1 --reject=gif -O x www.google.it
WARNING: combining -O with -r or -p will mean that all downloaded content
will be placed in the single file you specified.

2015-07-21 14:30:26 URL:http://www.google.it/ [18842/18842] -> "x" [1]
2015-07-21 14:30:26 URL:http://www.google.it/robots.txt [8170] -> "x" [1]
2015-07-21 14:30:26 URL:http://www.google.it/images/srpr/nav_logo80.png [35615/35615] -> "x" [1]
...

$ cat x| sed -e 's/href="/\nhref="/g' | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*"\).*/\1/p'
/search?"
/AA61D1355AF544A297B61B2A6E00FF1C&css_id=bubble.min.css"
http://www.google.it/imghp?hl=it&tab=wi"
http://maps.google.it/maps?hl=it&tab=wl"
https://play.google.com/?hl=it&tab=w8"
http://www.youtube.com/?gl=IT&tab=w1"
...
```